# Historic-geographic spread and variations of the children's rhyme "My friend Billy had a 10-foot willy"

Tags: folklore

Around the turn of the 1970s a rhyme was sung by small children in southern England:

> My friend Billy had a 10-foot willy.
>   He showed it to the girl next door (or: He put it through the neighbour's door).
>   She thought it was a snake,
>   Hit it with a rake,
>   And now it's only four foot four

What was its historic-geographic spread and what were some of its variants?

Comment: What if `foor`? https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/foor

Comment: This is a "whale of a tale". The [blue whale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_whale_penis) has the largest penis known to mankind (3 meters (9.8 feet). That is 10 feet in my books!

Comment: See also the same question on Literature SE https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/5395/139

Answer (score 8):

This orally transmitted children's rhyme has been recorded in many memorates and is discussed in the anthropological literature about this genre of folklore.

**Historic-geographic spread**

It is known to have been current **in the late 1950s and up until the 1970s**, and it was sung in places that include

- **Britain** (England, Scotland, and Northern Ireland) and
- **the Antipodes** (Australia and New Zealand).

**Variants**

Variations have been reported in

- the **identity of the unfortunate protagonist**,
- the **final length of his organ** once he has received the arguably rather disproportionate comeuppance for his pride, and
- the **level of specification of the reptile** for which it gets mistaken.

*a) Identity of the protagonist*

Ian Turner et al, in their work *Cinderella Dressed in Yella* (1978), report a variant current in Melbourne, Australia, between 1962 and 1973 featuring **"Old King Cole"**, who is also the protagonist in one of the best known rhymes in the 4/4 time which is widespread in this genre.

A version with **"Good King Billy"** is reported in Northern Ireland, which I have found online in a memorate and which is referred to in Hamish MacDonald's *The Gravy Star* (1999) and by Michael Rosen in his *Penguin Book of Childhood* (1995), dated to 1958.

Other variants have "**My cousin Billy**", "**My Uncle Billy**", and "**Buffalo Bill**".

*b) Length of his body part at the end of the rhyme*

"**Four foot four**" is the most common end state, but versions have been recorded with "**two foot foor**" or "**five foot four**". (Jonathan Blyth, *The Law Of The Playground: A Puerile and Disturbing Dictionary of Playground Insults and Games*, 2004.)

*c) The reptile that the second party believes she sees*

In most recorded versions, the second party - whether she is described as the girl next door or as a neighbour - mistakes the protagonist's penis for a generic **snake**. But in her article "The Subversive World of New Zealand Playground Rhymes" (*Journal of Folklore Research* 44 [2-3], 2007), Janice Ackerley records a variant in which it is specifically imagined as a **viper**, the third and fourth lines being "I shot it with a sniper [sic] / 'Cos I thought it was a viper". (This is also the only variant I am aware of in which the respondent to the act of pride appears in the first person.)

**Published sources**

In addition to the five sources mentioned above, other published references to the rhyme appear in Martyn Hammersley and Peter Woods, ed., *Gender and Ethnicity in Schools: Ethnographic Accounts* (1993); Iona Opie, *The Singing Game* (1998); Eve Bearne and Victor Watson, *Where Texts and Children's Meet* (1999); Catherine Fox, *Love for the Lost* (2015); and Anthony McGowan, *The Art of Failing: Notes from the Underdog* (2017).